# MvvmLight message not firing when using local/anonymous action

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

MvvmLight messenger sometimes doesn't work when I use an anonymous action. If I pass a member variable or method as the action it works fine, but using an anonymous lambda or local variable doesn't work.

```
    private SongCollection songCollection;
    Action<bool> c;
    public MyService(SongCollection songCollection)
    {
        this.songCollection = songCollection;

        Action<bool> a = (bool isLoading) =>
        {
            ChangeSong(songCollection.GetFirstSong());
        }; 

        Action<bool> b = OnLoadingComplete; //Using this instead of 'a' works.
        //c = a; //Uncommenting this line makes it work, even if using 'a'.

        Messenger.Default.Register<bool>(this, "IsLoading", a); //Doesn't work.
    }
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with garbage collection or the way MvvmLight does works behind the scenes. Or am I missing something obvious?

I'm using version MvvmLight `4.3.31.1` on .Net4.0.

Comment: The code you have works just fine for me (using the same versions as you -- .NET 4.0 and MvvmLight 4.3.31.1). Something must be causing your `MyService` to get garbage collected when using 'a', but not when using 'b' or 'c'. But I can't think what it would be.

Comment: What are the definitions of `OnLoadingComplete` and `DoSomething`?

Comment: Both are the same: `ChangeSong(songCollection.GetFirstSong());` but a breakpoint in either won't be hit.

Comment: The service is used quite a bit so shouldn't be garbage collected. Using 'c' works because the reference in MyService is remains, unlike the local variables in the constructor. I'd expect the local variables to be garbage collected if it weren't for the messenger holding onto the action.

Comment: Are these methods public, private, or protected?

Comment: songCollection is private. Added detail to example. Just noticed that using `ChangeSong(this.songCollection.GetFirstSong())` works. Not sure if I should set that as an answer as I thought the closure would have access to both variables.

Comment: Like I said, I couldn't duplicate your problem with a simple test project. Perhaps you should try creating a new project and see what the minimum code is to duplicate your error. If there's a bug in the messenger, the project will be very helpful in getting it fixed.