# MVVM Light Messenger working only occasionally

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-runtime, mvvm-light, uwp

I am facing the following problem. 
I am implementing a Hamburger Menu using a SplitView. In the SplitView pane I use a UserControl and a View Model to back it (let's call it SplitViewUserControlVM).

From this SplitViewUserControlVM I send messages to other VMs in the application. In most of the cases this works fine. However there is a VM that does not always receive the messages(lets call it ProblemVM). I have not found a pattern as to when it does and when it doesn't it seems more or less random.

Below is the code for the registration to the Messenger and sending the messages.

In the ProblemVM constructor

```
 MessengerInstance.Register<bool>(this, "LoginStatusChanged", (b) =>
        {
            navigationService.NavigateTo("MainPage");
        });
```

In a method of the SplitViewUserControlVM

```
  //Notify other view models of changes in login status
  MessengerInstance.Send<bool>(false, "LoginStatusChanged");
```

or

```
 //Notify other view models of changes in login status
 MessengerInstance.Send<bool>(true, "LoginStatusChanged");
```

I used breakpoints to check whether the registration happens before the message is sent and all seems well. Does anybody know why the message is not always received?

If it helps. In the ProblemVM I also use the messenger to communicate with the associated View in some cases. The registration happens in the `OnNavigatedTo` method in the View. This scenario also works ok.

EDIT: I just noticed that changing the lambda in the registration to a private method seems to solve the problem. I found this in this question [MvvmLight message not firing when using local/anonymous action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576000/mvvmlight-message-not-firing-when-using-local-anonymous-action). However there is no explanation why.

Comment: Read this explanation: https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7640

Comment: @kubakista Thank you, this explains the problem. If you would like to make your comment into an answer with a little more depth I will accept it.